# Git push master origin not working

Tags: git, github

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first) error: failed to
>   push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/repo.git': Updates
>   were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not
>   have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>    to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote
>   changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See
>   the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: The answer is right there in the error message...

Comment: I'm new to GitHub. @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else is working with you on the same repository, and they have made some changes that you don't have locally, so first you need to do

```
git pull origin master
```

After that solve conflicts if there are any, and at the end you can do

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

> You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again

Pull first, then push to remote because remote has commit(s) that doesn't exist in local.

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to pull down work from remote. The smoothest way may be `git fetch` followed by `git rebase` or as the message suggests `git pull`. The former will redo your work on top of the remote work; the latter will create a new commit.

If you're *certain* you don't care about what's in the remote repository, you can `git push -f`, but it's a dangerous operation where your remote will lose old state.

This suggests some other work merged between the last time you grabbed the remote repository and the time you're pushing. Maybe a pull request that you merged or someone else's work?

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, i am new in using GitHub.